# Stack Haddock - Do not generate docs for dependencies

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haddock

I am generating my haddocks with:

`stack haddock  --no-haddock-deps`

My understanding of this option from the help:

`Enable/disable building Haddocks for dependencies`

would be that it would not generate haddocks for any dependencies. But this is not the case. It generates two html files:

`Updating Haddock index for local packages in
/myDir/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-6.16/7.10.3/doc/index.html
Updating Haddock index for local packages and dependencies in
/myDir/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-6.16/7.10.3/doc/all/index.html`

I do not want docs for the dependencies. Only my modules. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are just index files, containing links to all of the available documented modules. The creation of a local packages + dependencies index does not mean that it is in fact creating documentation for the dependencies, just that it's updating that index for your local packages.

Comment: OK. So the index page of the dependencies will not be included in the distribution?

Comment: I don't know what distribution means here.

Comment: When you create your package for hackage.

Comment: If you mean `stack sdist` or `stack upload`, it never includes generated HTML of any form.

Comment: @GreenSaguaro Hackage creates its own haddock documentation -- you never upload it yourself.